# Error when trying to build project in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When trying to build my project in the angular CLI, i am given this error. I've read around a tried a few things but nothing has worked. The error is:

> ERROR in src\app\dropdown\dropdown.component.html(8,12): : Property
>   'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }[]'.
>   src\app\dropdown\dropdown.component.html(34,6): : Property 'name' does
>   not exist on type '{ name: string; }[]'.
>   src\app\dropdown\dropdown.component.html(8,12): : Property 'name' does
>   not exist on type '{ name: string; }[]'.
>   src\app\dropdown\dropdown.component.html(8,45): : Property 'name' does
>   not exist on type '{ name: string; }[]'.

HTML for component:

```
<div id="Header">
<h1>Welcome to  the BOV Solicitor info app!</h1>
</div>
<h3>Select a Municipality from the drop down box to display the information.</h3>
<hr>
<div id="Dropdown">  
  Select Municipality :  
  <select  [(ngModel)]="ProductHeader.name" (ngModelChange)="SearchProduct(ProductHeader.name)">  
       <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductHeader">{{prod.name}}</option>  
   </select> 
   <br>
   <br>
   <!--
       Code for future feature


<h3 style="color: red;">If you wish to view all records, click the button instead of making a selection in the drop down box.</h3>
   <div class="allrecords">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="toggleChild()">Click to display all records</button>
    <div>
        <app-allrecords [showMePartially]="showVar"></app-allrecords>
    </div>
</div>

-->







</div>  
<div>  
<div *ngIf="ProductHeader.name">   
<h4>{{ProductHeader.name}} Details:</h4>  
<div>
<table class="table  table-dark table-hover table-bordered table-responsive-lg">  
    <tr >   
        <th>Attorney:</th> <th>Solicitor For:</th>  <th>Phone:</th> <th>Fax:</th>   <th>Address:</th>
    </tr>  

     <tr  *ngFor="let Prod of ProductDetails">  
        <td>{{Prod.Atty1}}</td>  
        <td>{{Prod.Affil1}}</td>  
        <td>{{Prod.Phone}}</td>  
        <td>{{Prod.Fax}}</td>  
        <td>{{Prod.Add}}</td>
    </tr>  
  <tr  *ngFor="let Prod of ProductDetails">  
     <td>{{Prod.Atty2}}</td>  
     <td>{{Prod.Affil2}}</td>  
     <td>{{Prod.Phone2}}</td>  
     <td>{{Prod.Fax2}}</td>  
     <td>{{Prod.Add2}}</td>
 </tr>


</table>
<h3>Please report any errors or outdated information <a href="mailto:joebarrett29@gmail.com?subject=Report&body=The following information needs changed:">here</a>.</h3>  
</div>
```

Code for the TS component:
Had to cut some data to meet the input limit for stack overflow

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DropdownComponent  {
  showVar: boolean = true;



    toggleChild(){
        this.showVar = !this.showVar;
    }

   //Create a object for storing filter data and bind to html table.
   public ProductDetails: object = [];  

   //filter product details on name and return productDetails object.
   public ProductHeader = [{ name: 'Alepo Twp' }, { name: 'Aspinwall Borough'}, { name: 'Avalon Borough' }, { name: 'Baldwin' },
   { name: 'Baldwin Twp' }, { name: 'Bell Acres Borough' }, { name: 'Bellevue Borough' }, { name: 'Ben Avon' }, 
   { name: 'Ben Avon Heights' }, { name: 'Bethel Park Borough' }, { name: 'Blawnox' }, { name: 'Brackenridge' },
   { name: 'Braddock Borough' }, { name: 'Braddock Hills' }, { name: 'Bradford Woods' }, { name: 'Brentwood Borough' },
   { name: 'Bridgeville' }, { name: 'Carnegie' }, { name: 'Castle Shannon' }, { name: 'Chalfant' }, { name: 'Cheswick' },
   { name: 'Churchill' }, { name: 'City of Duquesne' }, { name: 'City of McKeesport' }, { name: 'City of Pittsburgh' },
   { name: 'Clairton' }, { name: 'Collier Twp' }, { name: 'Coraopolis' }, { name: 'Crafton Borough' }, { name: 'Crescent' },
   { name: 'Dormont Borough' }, { name: 'Dravosburg' }, { name: 'East Deer Twp' }, { name: 'East Pittsburgh' }, { name: 'Edgewood' },
   { name: 'Edgeworth Borough' }, { name: 'Elizabeth' }, { name: 'Elizabeth Twp' }, { name: 'Emsworth Borough' },
   { name: 'Etna' }, { name: 'Fawn Twp' }, { name: 'Findlay Twp' }, { name: 'Forest Hills Borough' }, { name: 'Forward Twp' }, { name: 'Fox Chapel Borough'},
   { name: 'Frazer Twp' }, { name: 'Glassport' }, { name: 'Glenfield' }, { name: 'Greentree Borough' }, { name: 'Hampton Twp' },
   { name: 'Harmar Twp' }, { name: 'Harrison Twp' }, { name: 'Haysville' }, { name: 'Heidelberg' }, { name: 'Homestead Borough' },
   { name: 'Imperial Twp' }, { name: 'Indiana Twp' }, { name: 'Ingram' }, { name: 'Jefferson' }, { name: 'Kennedy Twp' },
   { name: 'Kilbuck Twp' }, { name: 'Leet Twp' }, { name: 'Leetsdale' }, { name: 'Liberty' }, { name: 'Lincoln' }, { name: 'Marshall Twp' },
   { name: 'McCandless Twp' }, { name: 'McDonald' }, { name: 'McKees Rocks' }, { name: 'Millvale' }, { name: 'Monroeville Borough' },
   { name: 'Moon Twp' }, { name: 'Mount Oliver' }, { name: 'Mt. Lebanon Twp' }, { name: 'Munhall Borough' }, { name: 'Neville Twp' },
   { name: 'North Braddock Borough' }, { name: 'North Fayette' }, { name: 'North Fayette Twp' }, { name: 'North Versailles' }, 
   { name: 'Oakdale' }, { name: 'Oakmont Borough' }, { name: "O'Hara Twp" }, { name: 'Ohio Twp' }, { name: 'Osborne' },
   { name: 'Penn Hills Twp' }, { name: 'Pennsbury' }, { name: 'Pine Twp' }, { name: 'Pitcarin Borough' }, { name: 'Pleasant Hills Borough' },
   { name: 'Plum' }, { name: 'Port Vue Borough' }, { name: 'Rankin' }, { name: 'Reserve Twp' }, { name: 'Richland Twp' }, { name: 'Robinson Twp' },
   { name: 'Ross Twp' }, { name: 'Rosslyn Farms' }, { name: 'Scott' }, { name: 'Sewickley Borough' }, { name: 'Sewickley Heights Borough' },
   { name: 'Sewickley Hills' }, { name: 'Shaler Twp' }, { name: 'Sharpsburg' }, { name: 'South Fayette' }, { name: 'South Park Twp' },
   { name: 'South Versailles' }, { name: 'Springdale' }, { name: 'Springdale Twp' }, { name: 'Stowe Twp' }, { name: 'Swissvale' },
   { name: 'Tarentum' }, { name: 'Thornburg' }, { name: 'Trafford' }, { name: 'Turtle Creek' }, { name: 'Upper St. Clair Twp' },
   { name: 'Verona' }, { name: 'Versailles' }, { name: 'Wall' }, { name: 'West Deer Twp' }, { name: 'West Elizabeth Twp' },
   { name: 'West Elizabeth Twp' }, { name: 'West Homestead' }, { name: 'West Mifflin Borough' }, { name: 'West View' },
   { name: 'Whitaker' }, { name: 'White Oak' }, { name: 'Whitehall' }, { name: 'Wilkins Twp' }, { name: 'Wilkinsburg Borough' },
   { name: 'Wilmerding Borough' }];  
   public Products = [  
    {Name:'Alepo Twp', Atty1: 'Harlan S. Stone, Esq.' , Atty2: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Quaker Valley)', Phone: '412-392-5295', Phone2: '412-594-5622',
    Fax: '412-392-5367', Fax2: '412-594-5619', Add: '2 PPG Place Ste 400, Pittsburgh, PA 15222', Add2: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222'},

    {Name:'Aspinwall Borough', Atty1: 'Stephen L. Korbel, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Paul Giuffre, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Fox Chapel)', Phone: '412-394-5627', Phone2: '412-781-7900',
     Fax: '412-586-1042', Fax2: '412-781-7901', Add: '603 Stanwix Street, 6th Floor, Pittsburgh, PA 15222', Add2: '221 Commercial Avenue, Suite 220, Pittsburgh, PA 15215'}, 

    {Name:'Avalon Borough', Atty1: 'Megan M. Turnbull, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Anthony Giglio, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Northgate)', Phone: '412-391-9890', Phone2: '412-243-9700',
     Fax: '412-391-9685', Fax2: '412-243-9660', Add: '445 Fort Pitt Blvd., Suite 503, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '1500 Ardmore Blvd., Ste 506, Pittsburgh, PA 15221'},

    {Name:'Baldwin', Atty1: 'Stanley Lederman, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Ira Weiss, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Baldwin-Whitehall)', Phone: '412-261-5400', Phone2: '412-391-9890', 
    Fax: '412-281-0313', Fax2: '412-392-9685', Add: '428 Forbes Ave, Ste 302, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '445 Fort Pitt Blvd., Suite 503, Pittsburgh, PA 15219'},

    {Name:'Baldwin Twp', Atty1: 'Romel L. Nicholas, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Ira Weiss, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Baldwin-Whitehall)', Phone: '412-391-6920', Phone2: '412-391-9890', 
    Fax: '412-391-1189', Fax2: '412-391-9685', Add: '519 Court Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '445 Fort Pitt Blvd., Suite 503, Pittsburgh, PA 15219'},

    {Name:'Bell Acres Borough', Atty1: 'Robert Max Junker, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Patrick Clair, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Quaker Valley)', Phone: '412-394-5400', Phone2: '412-935-4777',
    Fax: '412-773-7862', Fax2: '412-935-4123', Add: '810 3rd Street, Beaver, PA 15009', Add2: '2100 Georgetown Dr, Suite 300, Sewickley, PA 15143'},

    {Name:'Bellevue Borough', Atty1: 'Thomas P. McDermott, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Anthony Giglio, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Northgate)', Phone: '412-391-6920', Phone2: '412-243-9700', 
    Fax: '412-391-1189', Fax2: '412-243-9660', Add: '519 Court Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '1500 Ardmore Blvd., Suite 506, Pittsburgh, PA 15221'},

  {Name:'Ben Avon', Atty1: 'Anne Sweeney, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Anthony Giglio, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Avonworth)', Phone: '412-366-3533', Phone2: '412-243-9700', 
    Fax: '412-366-3334', Fax2: '412-243-9660', Add: '1004 McKnight Park Drive, Pittsburgh, PA 15237', Add2: '1500 Ardmore Blvd., Suite 506, Pittsburgh, PA 15221'},

  {Name:'Ben Avon Heights', Atty1: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Anthony Giglio, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Avonworth)', Phone: '412-594-5622', Phone2: '412-243-9700', 
    Fax: '412-594-5619', Fax2: '412-243-9660', Add: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222', Add2: '1500 Ardmore Blvd., Suite 506, Pittsburgh, PA 15221'},

  {Name:'Bethel Park Borough', Atty1: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Anthony Giglio, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Bethel Park)', Phone: '412-594-5622', Phone2: '412-243-9700', 
    Fax: '412-594-5619', Fax2: '412-243-9660', Add: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222', Add2: '1500 Ardmore Blvd., Suite 506, Pittsburgh, PA 15221'},

  {Name:'Blawnox', Atty1: 'John F. Cambest, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Paul Guiffre, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Fox Chapel)', Phone: '412-243-1600', Phone2: '412-781-7900', 
    Fax: '412-243-1643', Fax2: '412-781-7901', Add: '1900 Main Street, Suite 207, Canonsburg, PA 15317', Add2: '221 Commercial Ave, Suite 200, Pittsburgh, PA 15215'},

  {Name:'Brackenridge', Atty1: 'David P. Hivzdos, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Ira Weiss, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Highland)', Phone: '724-941-5400', Phone2: '412-391-9890', 
    Fax: '724-941-8455', Fax2: '412-391-9685', Add: '505 Valleybrook Road, McMurray, PA 15317', Add2: '445 Fort Pitt Blvd., Suite 503, Pittsburgh, PA 15219'},

    {Name:'Braddock Borough', Atty1: 'Falco Muscante, Esq.' , Atty2: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Woodland Hills)', Phone: '412-242-4400', Phone2: '412-594-5622', 
    Fax: '412-242-4377', Fax2: '412-594-5619', Add: '424 South 27th Street, Suite 210, Pittsburgh, PA 15203', Add2: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222'},

    {Name:'Braddock Hills', Atty1: 'Samuel P. Kamin, Esq.' , Atty2: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Woodland Hills)', Phone: '412-281-1119', Phone2: '412-594-5622', 
    Fax: '412-281-1121', Fax2: '412-594-5619', Add: '437 Grant Street, Suite 1806, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222'},

    {Name:'Bradford Woods', Atty1: 'Kate M. Diersen, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Alfred C. Maiello, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (North Allegheny)', Phone: '412-281-0587', Phone2: '412-242-4400', 
    Fax: '412-281-2971', Fax2: '412-242-4377', Add: '437 Grant Street, 14th Floor, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '424 South 27th Street, Suite 210, Pittsburgh, PA 15203'},

    {Name:'Brentwood Borough', Atty1: 'Gavin A. Robb, Esq.' , Atty2: 'John T. Vogel, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Brentwood)', Phone: '412-594-5654', Phone2: '412-594-5622', 
    Fax: '412-594-5619', Fax2: '412-594-5619', Add: 'One PPG Place, Suite 1500, Pittsburgh, PA 15222', Add2: '1500 One PPG Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15222'},

    {Name:'Bridgeville', Atty1: 'Thomas P. McDermott, Esq.' , Atty2: 'Patrick Clair, Esq.', 
    Affil1: 'Municipality', Affil2: 'School District (Chartiers Valley)', Phone: '412-391-6920', Phone2: '412-935-4777', 
    Fax: '412-391-1189', Fax2: '412-935-4123', Add: '519 Court Place, Pittsburgh, PA 15219', Add2: '2100 Georgetown Dr, Suite 300, Sewickley, PA 15143'},







































    ]; 


   getProducts() {  
    console.log("getProducts");  
    return this.ProductHeader;  
}  


SearchProduct(name: string) {  

    let obj = this.Products.filter(m => m.Name == name);  
    this.ProductDetails = obj;  
    return this.ProductDetails;  
}  





  constructor() { 
    this.getProducts();  
  }

  ngOnInit() {





}


}
```

Comment: Your ProductHeader is array of object, not a simple object. So you need find one object from a index then you can do this like, you can do this ProductHeader[0].name

Comment: ^^ or if its optional then do [(ngModel)]="ProductHeader?.name" this will supress the error

Comment: Adding the "?" created an error on the data being called in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of adding --prod, just running build ran smoothly and the program is functioning without issue. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused by the line

`[(ngModel)]="ProductHeader.name" (ngModelChange)="SearchProduct(ProductHeader.name)"`

in your HTML, because the `name` value is inside each member of the array `ProductHeader`. You can access the value with `ProductHeader[i].name` where `i` is a number representing the index of the value you want.

In this case, it looks like you don't want the `name` values to be updated, you just want one to be selected. So I believe you could use a different variable for your ngModel, which would be defined in your component class, for example:

`[(ngModel)]="selectedProductName" (ngModelChange)="SearchProduct()"`

You also need to update the following line's `<option>` tag and add `[ngValue]="prod.name"`.

*Note: this would require updating your `SearchProduct()` function take no inputs and use the value `this.selectedProductName` instead.*

Comment: Would this mean i would have to change how the array content is displayed in the table in the HTML code?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that... the `<div *ngIf="ProductHeader.name"> ` line also contains the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with binding to an array for ngModel in the select. Try this:

Template:

```
  <select  [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct?.name"  (ngModelChange)="SearchProduct(ProductHeader.name)">  
       <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductHeader">{{prod.name}}</option>  
   </select>
```

Controller

```
export class DropdownComponent  {
  ...
  public ProductHeader = [ ... ]
  public selectedProd = ProductHeader[0];
  ...
```

Comment: This is Giving an error cannot identify ProductHeader. Am i missing a step?